# sin(x) autocorrelation function python

Tags: python, autocorrelation

I have a time-series data, and I want to show the autocorrelation function.
(We know that the autocorrelation of sine function is a cosine function)

I apply several ways to do this as follows

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf

x = np.arange(0,30,0.1)  #interval=0.1, 300 samples
y = np.sin(x)
y_cor = np.correlate(y,y,'full')  
lags = np.arange(-x[-1],x[-1]+0.1,0.1)

#sin(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)

#autocorrelation(numpy)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(lags,y_cor)
plt.xlabel('Lag')
plt.ylabel('autocorrelation')

#matplotlib
plt.figure()
plt.acorr(y,maxlags=y.size-1)

#statsmodels
plt.figure()
plot_acf(y,lags=y.size-1)

plt.show()
```

However, the result is a decaying cosine function, not a pure cos(x).
I've seen some answers say that it's because the package filling in zeros outside of the x region when computing auto-correlation, but how to fix this to get a pure cos(x)?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the autocorrelation function you're using is *biased.*. The unbiased estimate applies a [Bartlett window](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Biased_Sample_Autocorrelation.html) (triangular window) to attempt to undo the bias.